# Events between Classes not knowing each other? (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, event-handling

again me^^

I searched the forum but I think I didn't found a solution which suits my needs.
I got a MainView with a MainViewModel and open a new window MediaPlayerView with a kind of MVVM Windowopener (delegate). This MediaPlayerView has another MediaPlayerViewModel as DataContext. My Question is, how I can handle Events from my MediaPlayerView in my MainViewModel? I.e. I want my MainViewModel to do something if my MediaPlayerView.Closed Event is fired but my MediaPlayerView is made through a delegate and does not "know" the ViewModel nor the other way round. Can I rewrite it to suit my needs?

Here the Code of the Delegate I found here:

```
public interface IWindowFactory<T>
{
     void CreateNewWindow(T t);
}
public class MediaPlayerWindowFactory : IWindowFactory<string>
{
    public void CreateNewWindow(string directLink)
    {
         MediaPlayerView window = new MediaPlayerView(directLink);
         window.Show();
    }
}
```

And I open my window in my MainViewModel with

```
private readonly MediaPlayerWindowFactory windowFactory;
openMediaPlayerWindow(link);

private void openMediaPlayerWindow(string link)
{
    windowFactory.CreateNewWindow(link);
}
```

If this does not work, could you tell me another way to open windows in MVVM with event handling supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how I can handle Events from my MediaPlayerView in my MainViewModel?
>   I want my MainViewModel to do something if my MediaPlayerView.Closed Event is fired but my MediaPlayerView [...] does not "know" the ViewModel nor the other way round

The obvious answer is: *through a third party they both know*

That third party can be a specialized service or a general one like Prism's `EventAggregator`. Important thing is only that the two view models that want to communicate get the same instance of the service.

So the route is basically this:

`MediaPlayerView.Closed` -> `MediaPlayerViewModel.ClosedCommand` -> `ThirdParty` -> `MainViewModel.ReactToTheEvent`

And it could be wired up like this:

```
internal class MediaPlayerViewModel
{
    public MediaPlayerViewModel( IEventAggregator eventAggregator )
    {
        MediaPlayerClosedCommand = new DelegateCommand( () => eventAggregator.GetEvent<MediaPlayerClosedEvent>().Publish() );
    }

    public ICommand MediaPlayerClosedCommand { get; }
}

internal class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel( IEventAggregator eventAggregator )
    {
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<MediaPlayerClosedEvent>().Subscribe( ReactToTheEvent );
    }

    private void ReactToTheEvent()
    {
        // do something
    }
}

public class MediaPlayerClosedEvent : PubSubEvent
{
}
```

plus a little bit of `System.Windows.Interactivity` somewhere in `MediaPlayerView`:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closed">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MediaPlayerClosedCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Wow okay that really sounds obvious :P I got one other question. My MediaPlayerView holds my mediaelement. If the view fires an event, am I allowed to handle it directly in the view regarding mvvm? It seems useless to fire event to viewmodel which would fire back :P

Comment: I'd say yes, if the event is only interesting for the view anyway. So it depends on the event and how you handle it.

Comment: Damn I have another problem now... tried to do as you said but before I could test I remembered that I have to do async things (html requests) in my MainViewModel I redirected the event to. I think this isn't supported by this approach right? Do you have an Idea how to do this? An approach would to not do it async and eventually causing UI Freezes on MainView which wouldn't matter because we are watching a movie in the other window.

Comment: I tried it now with 
`eventAggregator.GetEvent<MediaEndedEvent>().Subscribe(async () => await OnMediaEnded());`
But I don't think that this is waiting on the task to finish... It's just a small request but if internet is too slow I think it can't handle it :S